# error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type

Tags: c++11

I have a legacy code in C++, which is having a statement as below

```
auto &&res = Message(MessageType::SetPort);
```

and the error I am getting while compiling the above code is as stated below

> ```
> error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type.
> ```

The code was developed using Visual Studio 2012 and now I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 edition to compile this. How to get rid of this error? I am not good in C++/CLI. Someone told me that this is a CLI code. Kindly guide me to the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing what `Message` is it is a bit unclear. I would just remove `&&` whatsoever, or use `const auto&`.